# Time Machine backup folder getting twice as big on other hdd?

Tags: macos, partitioning, backup, external-hard-drive, transfer

So i have an old 1TB HDD for my Time Machine backups. Its nearly full (950gb used) and now i decided to move to a bigger HDD (i buyed a 5TB drive, but made partitions to split it to 2TB and 3TB, the 2TB was meant for backups). Now i read a guide how to transfer backups and it says to deactivate the "ignore owner" thing and then just copy the backup folder from the old drive to the new one.

I did this and as i expected, it took really long. But after about 9 hours of preparing (i dont know why but it had to prepare kind of every single file) and 10 hours of copying i noticed the size of the copy getting bigger then 1TB. I thought maybe its just a bug and waited another 9 hours. I also noticed, that the indicator for the complete size of the folder slowly got bigger, which i thought is because my mac cannot calculate the whole size right and has to correct it once it notices the copy is bigger than thought (on the drive it tells me the folder is 487gb big, but since nothing else is on the drive and the drive says it has only 50gb left, its clear my mac cannot calculate this).

But after the said 9 additional hours it told me the drive is full and it cannot copy anymore. I looked at the 2TB partition and it said its full. But how did something from a 1TB HDD get bigger than a 2TB drive? And i checked, it got 36 of 45 backup-folders (the ones with the dates). How does this happen? is there a way to prevent this? because i really want to transfer my backups

the only thing i could think of is making an image of the 1TB and copying it to the 2TB where i "unpack" the backup folder into the 2TB, but this never worked because disk utility always fails at deactivating the 1TB (manual deactivation is working, but even if the drive is manually deactivated it still fails)

Comment: Are both your old drive & new drive formatted GUID/HFS+? Did you also switch off TM before you started copying? Your symptom is that the copy is not following the hard links correctly & trying to make a new copy for each link it finds. Ref: https://support.apple.com/HT202380

Comment: i formatted the new drive in Mac OS Extended (Journaled) before the backups (as told in the article) and the old one already was. i also noticed the switch for turning off time machine is gone. has it moved to another position? the other tutorial just told me to turn time machine backups off, which i assumed to be the box for auto backups.

Comment: found out that the button was removed in sierra and "replaced" by the checkbox for auto backups
Ref: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7693290

Comment: Did you also check they're GUID not MBR?

Comment: MBR? i did not found this in the information of any drive, but the newer one was partionioned with GUID-Partitiontables. The older one was also wiped and formatted with this pc which lets me think it is. But how can i check this? Disk Utility gave me much information, but nothing about GUID

Comment: Disk Utility >View Menu > Show all devices, then select the actual drive not the partition. Partition Map is then in the info pane.

Comment: Checked, both are GUID

Comment: I now tried something: i hooked up time machine to the new drive to make a test backup and time machine is now cleaning up the old backups. It takes extremely long (2h for 30gb freed up) but at least its a bit of progress. Still, it would be nicer to find a solution for the initial problem

Comment: It ran a few hours and then stopped at 133gb freed up. I dont know why

Comment: tbh, I'm not sure why this happens to some people in some situations - people appear to be following the instructions properly, but for some reason the hard links aren't correctly followed.

Comment: Just to tie these two seemingly related yet unanswered questions together in the side bar - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366802/time-machine-backups-backupdb-uses-way-too-much-space-when-copied-to-another-vo